# How write function in onclick button attribut

Tags: javascript, onclick, click

I'm trying to use a function directly in the attribute onclick of my button, but i have always an error.
Example:

```
<button onclick="function() { alert('hello'); }">Click me</button>
```

And the result is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: All you're trying to do is *define* a function, which wouldn't visibly accomplish anything anyway.  Just invoke the code you're trying to invoke: `onclick="alert('hello')"`  If you want to define a function, do that separately in your JavaScript code and just invoke the function in `onclick`.  (Or, even better, attach it as a handler from the JavaScript code so you're not writing in-line JavaScript in your HTML.)

Answer (score 4):

no need to make it a function, just list the statements:

```
<button onclick="alert('hello');alert('hello 2');alert('hello 3');">Click me</button>
```

Comment: It was just an example, I have a complex code with also an ajax call inside the onclick, but the error is always the same

Comment: ok, you could update your question to better reflect your special case. Still. Why do you want to use an inline function? there are many other patterns you could use

Answer (score 2):

Below code will allow you to add function in your onclick attribute.

Click me

```html
<button onclick="javascript:(function() { alert('hello'); })()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code like this.

`<button onClick="alert('hello');">Click me</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like that if you want all of this in your html file

```html
    <script>
        function hello(){
       alert('hello')
        }
    </script>

    <button id="bait" onClick="hello()">
      Click me
    </button>
    <!-- OR -->
    <!-- <button onclick="javascript:(() => {alert('hello')})()"> -->
    <!-- But it's good for short function only -->
```

But I think you should use jQuery instead (if you can)

---

---

If you want to do so, just add a clickHandler function:

```js
    $("#bait").on("click", () => {
      alert('hello')
    })
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="bait">Click me </button>
```

A bit overkill for a prompt but I suppose you ask this for a trickier function so it'll be easier overall imo